# Lost in Space (1965) "Feet, do your stuff" reference

Tags: reference, lost-in-space-1965

In the Lost in Space (1965) second season episode "Curse of Cousin Smith", there is a scene in which the robot exclaims "feet, do your stuff" before making a hasty retreat.

The robot is obviously making a comical quote, but I can't figure out the reference. There is a line of similar intent "feet, don't fail me now" to which one can easily find attributions, but not the phrase as uttered by the robot. Since it is such an out-of-place line for the robot - he has no feet and he's not supposed to be emotional - it's obviously a joke reference, but to who/what?